# Convert C code to MASM32

Tags: c, assembly, migration, masm32

This seems a ridiculous question, but I really need to know an easy way to convert C code to  MASM32 code (with the .if's, .while's). The code has a single function, but it uses structs (which, I believe, exists in MASM). I know there are a few questions like this here, and some in other sites too, but I couldn't find, until this point, a solution to my specific problem (MASM32 readable, not c compiled low level obfuscated pure assembly). Does anyone know some sort of program that would made this miracle happen? It doesn't seem so difficult, as the macros in masm are pretty much just an uglier version of C...

Comment: C is a lot more expressive than MASM's macros, so a translation tool is not as easy to make as it might seem. How large is the code base you're trying to translate? What I'm getting at here is that if it's, say, 1000 lines or less then maybe it'll be faster to just translate it by hand. I don't really see the point though - not only is your MASM translation likely to be less efficient than the "obfuscated" compiler output, it's also likely to be less readable than the C code.

Comment: How long is the function? If it is only a single function, you could get started by rewriting the C code to something more like ASM, ie. limiting the number of variables in use and such. This would make it easier to translate.

Answer (score 1):

you can look for that command line parameter of the MicroSoft C compiler cl. Most of C compiler will provide that. Despite the output asm source code might be need modify few for MASM.